# Android - Set two built types to the same source folder

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-build-type

Until recently our Android app only had two buildTypes `debug` and `release`. We just added a `qa` build type and I'd like to **have the qa build type point to the debug source code**, so I don't have to duplicate the code. Is this possible?

The main difference between qa and debug is Proguard. Our build.gradle file looks like the following:

```
productFlavors {
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }

buildTypes {
    debug { 
        // no proguard
        // use debug code
    }
    qa { 
        // proguard
        // use debug code
    }
    release { 
        // proguard
        // use release code
    }
}
```

The file structure looks like this:

```
src
├── debug
│   ├── assets
│   ├── java
│   └── res
├── main
│   ├── java
│   └── res
├── release
│   ├── assets
│   ├── java
│   └── res
```

I have tried using sourceSets and it doesn't seem to work:

```
sourceSets {
    qa {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/debug/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was so close. I just needed to add the location of the android manifest file and the assets folder.

```
sourceSets {
    qa {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/debug/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/debug/assets']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines ought get you there:

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        qa {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        qa {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

though on further inspection this seems the same as your example above, the format I pasted does work for me however - maybe I'm missing the difference or maybe something else is to blame.

You can always hack up build.gradle and paste something like this in to make sure your changes have taken effect:

```
import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.*
println(
    prettyPrint(toJson(
        android.sourceSets.collectEntries {ss -> [ss.name, ss.java.toString()]}
    ))
)
```